# How to get selected value from Itemselector

Tags: extjs5

I have a Item Selector, which has 2 sections, Avaliable Column and Selected Column.

I want to fetch all values from selected column and store it in a List.

How to do that ?

```
items : [{
                    // first column
                    xtype : 'itemselector',
                    columnWidth: 0.5,
                    store: showFieldStore,
                    id: 'fieldSelector',
                    displayField: 'columnLabel',
                    valueField: 'dataIndex',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    fromTitle: 'Available Columns',
                    toTitle: 'Selected Columns'
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to display values as a string list or from display fields :

```
itemSelectorField.toField.store.getRange().collect("display_value_propery_name").join(",");
```

Comment: Thanks 

`var itemSelectorField = Ext.getCmp('fieldSelector'),
     fieldList = itemSelectorField.toField.store.getRange();`